# How to print Bar code 39 on star tsp future PRNT

Tags: code39

Hi am working on the Star TSP100 futurePRNT, have got a sample example to print data which is working fine. They use the code "\x1b\x1d\x61\x1" to allign to center. Need to know which coding it is? And how to print Code - 39 barcode in using the code?

Answer (score 0):

It's a hexadecimal code specified by the below lined document.

As an example I'll deconstruct this command:

```
1B = Ascii Escape Character. This denotes the beginning of the command.
1D = Ascii Group Separator Character. This is part of the command.
61 = Ascii numeral '1'. This is part of the command.
1  = Value. This is the only parameter of the command.
```

Consulting the linked specification, `1B 1D 61 a` is the command to specify position alignment. The `a` is the parameter. This command specifically sets center horizontal alignment (page 3-32).

The command to specify a barcode can be found on pages 3-43 through 3-46. It follows a similar format, there will be a code specifying the task, then a number of variable parameters to select the correct format, and finally you'll send your data.

Latest Line Mode Specification: http://www.starasia.com/%5CDownload%5CManual%5Cstarline_cm_en.pdf